# Jmeter- Null Pointer Exception when trying to login

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

Hey I am trying to login to a website using jmeter, but I end up getting a Null Pointer Exception.

I looked though the other stackoverflow questions but nothing has helped so far.
Then I tried recording my actions with Blazemeter and it runs on the Blazemeter console, but when I download the same .jmx file and try running it on the Jmeter, it tanks again.

Comment: Can you provide us your test plan or which element throws an exception?

Comment: please provide your question with a .jmx script you tried to run. Also add listener view results in tree to analyze when you obtain null pointer (on what step)

Comment: This is Doron from the BlazeMeter team. We just wanted to know if the issue has been resolved, please contact support@blazemeter.com if the problem still persists. Please note, BlazeMeter does offer scripting services as well as turnkey options for more in depth requirements. You can email support@blazemeter.com for these services as well.